# Unable to resolve "./ExpoTHREE" from "node_modules/expo-three/build/index.js" Error

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I encounter this error when I do 'expo start. How do i fix? 
Error Message: Unable to resolve "./ExpoTHREE" from "node_modules/expo-three/build/index.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.